# Public Overrides Function GetBytes() As Byte() is obsolete

Tags: security, cryptography, rijndael, obsolete, rfc2898

What does the poet try to say?

Public Overrides Function GetBytes() As Byte() is obsolete: Rfc2898DeriveBytes replaces PasswordDeriveBytes for deriving key material from a password and is preferred in new applications.

Should i replace this one...

```
Dim keyBytes As Byte()
keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)
```

...with what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing crucial part of your code. It is that part that declares password to be PasswordDeriveBytes. Change that to Rfc2898DeriveBytes and you are good.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Constructor needs parameters...fill in with yours
Dim password as new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(yourParamsHere)

Dim keyBytes As Byte()
keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like what you need is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes.aspx